# M1 chip, Install Puppeteer in Docker NodeJs, The chromium binary is not available for arm64

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, puppeteer, apple-m1

I got an error while building backend docker, specifically installing Puppeteer. I'm using M1 MacBook, and I found a solution on the local machine(https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6622), but this didn't work on the docker. Has anyone who has the same Puppeteer issue on the docker?

```
#12 15.58 npm ERR! code 1
#12 15.58 npm ERR! path /app/node_modules/puppeteer
#12 15.58 npm ERR! command failed
#12 15.58 npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
#12 15.58 npm ERR! The chromium binary is not available for arm64.
#12 15.58 npm ERR! If you are on Ubuntu, you can install with: 
#12 15.58 npm ERR! 
#12 15.58 npm ERR!  sudo apt install chromium
#12 15.58 npm ERR! 
#12 15.58 npm ERR! 
#12 15.58 npm ERR!  sudo apt install chromium-browser
#12 15.58 npm ERR! 
#12 15.58 npm ERR! /app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserFetcher.js:115
#12 15.58 npm ERR!                     throw new Error();
```

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true
ENV DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM "linux/amd64"
COPY . .
RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python3 && \
npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? A member of my team is facing the same issue. Please add an answer if you found a way to make it work. Thx

Answer (score 7):

This is the dockerfile that worked for me.

```
# reference https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/troubleshooting#setting_up_chrome_linux_sandbox
FROM node:current-alpine

# manually installing chrome
RUN apk add chromium

# skips puppeteer installing chrome and points to correct binary
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true \
    PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser

WORKDIR /app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]
RUN npm ci
# the rest of your dockerfile here
```

When launching puppeteer in js, make sure to add the following flags on launch

```
puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
```

You can read more about this in [google's docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/troubleshooting#setting_up_chrome_linux_sandbox)

Comment: I had to add the following command to install chromium on my M2 mac, but thanks for the tip! `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq chromium`

Comment: I inherited a project which used FROM node:14.17-buster instead of current-alpine. As such, I had to use apt-get instead of apk, just as @Fabio did above, along with the ENV statements.

Comment: I also had to change PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH to /usr/bin/chromium

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and this made it work for me: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/7740#issuecomment-970490323

It seems the npm installation cannot find a chromium binary for M1. To not make npm try to install Chromium, you can add `ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true`. But then I needed to also install the binary before running `npm install`, by adding `RUN apk add chromium` to the Dockerfile (if you are running the node alpine image).

Result:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true

RUN apk add chromium

# Add and install everything
```

Comment: I was trying to run a repo that contained `puppeteer`as a dependency and npm install didn't work on Mac, so I just prepended the environment variable with npm install and it worked: 

`PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true npm install`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is:

- using Docker
- doesn't want to switch to alpine
- having issues with `Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

you need to add the archive link to the container's `sources.list` like so:

```
# Patch sources list for chromium and other packages that have been archived
RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main" > /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score -2):

Add puppeteer env after building dependencies. Worked for me.

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.11

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./

RUN apk --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies add \
        python3 \
        make \
        g++

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

RUN npm install --quiet
RUN npm install -g pm2 --quiet

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm run build
RUN rm -rf ./src
```